# Optional job templates in YAML Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to optionally include templates based on some kind of template expression?  Specifically, I want my top-level definition in azure-pipelines.yml to call out which build job templates to use in an included stage template:

azure-pipelines.yml :

```
stages:
- template: generic-build-stage.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    # Example of optional build templates to use
    buildTypes: [SpecificBuildJobs1, SpecificBuildJobs3, SpecificBuildJobs4]
```

generic-build-stage.yml :

```
parameters:
  buildTypes: ???

stages:
- stage: generic_build
  jobs:
  ${{ }} # ???? What goes here to include the appropriate templates
  - template: ???
```

The template expression above would ideally expand to this:

```
  jobs:
  - template: specific-build-jobs1.yml
  - template: specific-build-jobs3.yml
  - template: specific-build-jobs4.yml
```

Edit: The "Iterative insertion" example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#iterative-insertion) seems to suggest that some form of dynamic, parse-time insertion is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method worked to allow a top-level pipeline definition to consume a variable number of job sets at a lower level.

azure-pipelines.yml :

```
stages:
- template: generic-build-stage.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    # Example of optional build templates to use
    buildTypes: [SpecificBuildJobs1, SpecificBuildJobs3, SpecificBuildJobs4]
```

generic-build-stage.yml :

```
parameters:
  buildTypes: [MissingBuildType] # Use this if buildTypes is not provided

stages:
  - stage: build_stage
    jobs:
    # Note: VS Code extension for Pipelines (1.1574.4) will
    # say this is an "Unexpected property", but this works in ADO

    - ${{ if containsValue(parameters.buildTypes, 'MissingBuildType') }}:
      - template: build-stage-null.yml
    - ${{ if containsValue(parameters.buildTypes, 'SpecificBuildJobs1') }}:
      - template: specific-build-jobs1.yml
    - ${{ if containsValue(parameters.buildTypes, 'SpecificBuildJobs2') }}:
      - template: specific-build-jobs2.yml
    - ${{ if containsValue(parameters.buildTypes, 'SpecificBuildJobs3') }}:
      - template: specific-build-jobs3.yml
    - ${{ if containsValue(parameters.buildTypes, 'SpecificBuildJobs4') }}:
      - template: specific-build-jobs4.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible, for the template reference is resolved at parse time.

You may have to set multiple templates for main pipeline, and set the value for `buildTypes` as the specific template name for job templates, and in `generic-build-stage.yml` use `- template:${{parameters.buildTypes}}.yml` to call corresponding job template;

Azure-pipelines.yml:

```
stages:
- template: generic-build-stage.yml 
  parameters:
      buildTypes:specific-build-jobs1  

- template: generic-build-stage.yml 
  parameters:
      buildTypes:specific-build-jobs3
```

generic-build-stage.yml

```
parameters:
  buildTypes: ""

stages:
- stage: generic_build
  jobs:
  - template: ${{parameters.buildTypes}}.yml
```

Comment: Yeah, it may not be possible, though all the information needed to do this is available at parse time.  Thanks Levi Lu.